# Why doesnt my button update to enabled after the command finishes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I'm currently looking into commands and what I've done as of right now is that I made a command, bound it to a button and I've passed in a `bool` property which will indicate whether or not the button can execute the command.

The issue is that the button starts off as enabled, and as soon as I click it, it turns disabled, and then the person gets added to the `ListView`, but the button stays disabled.

I'm not sure if I need to add a `UpdateSourceTrigger` to the command, I thought the whole point of implementing a `ObservableObject` was to not have to do that.

What's the proper way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve?

The Command

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

The MainWindow (DataContext)

```
<Window x:Class="Commands.MainWindow"
        ...
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="450"
        Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <ListView MinHeight="100"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleCollection}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

        <Button Content="Add"
                Width="100"
                Height="25"
                Command="{Binding AddPersonCommand}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The MainViewModel

```
internal class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<PersonModel> PeopleCollection { get; set; }

    /* A slow working command */
    public RelayCommand AddPersonCommand { get; set; }


    private bool _canExecute;
    public bool CanExecute
    {
        get { return _canExecute; }
        set
        {
            _canExecute = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CanExecute");
        }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CanExecute = true;
        PeopleCollection = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();
        AddPersonCommand = new RelayCommand(o => AddPersonToCollection(o), (p) => CanExecute);
    }

    private async void AddPersonToCollection(object o)
    {
        CanExecute = false;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            /* Simulate a heavy workload*/
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                PeopleCollection.Add(new PersonModel
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Foo bar"
                });
            });

            /* Property needs to be updated from the main thread? */
            //CanExecute = false;
        });

        CanExecute = false;
    }
}
```

The ObservableObject

```
internal class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb remark. In the last line of the `AddPersonToCollection` you set the `CanExecute` to `false`. Sounds to me that is why the button is disabled.

Comment: Smh.. That's it. Now it needs me to click the ListView after in order to update or.. "Refresh" the button state, but it works now at least!

Comment: If you bind the button's `IsEnabled` to CanExecute, shouldn't it handle the refresh of button state for you?

Comment: It should, but I've never had to do that before with Commands, it might be because it's async? I'm not sure.

Comment: If canexecute returns false then the button is disabled. Canexecute will automatically be checked if there's user interaction seems to be relevant. If there isn't then you have to CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();

Comment: @Andy YES! That's it, I noticed it updated it there was user interaction such as focusing the control. I've been looking for that so long! I tried doing this `Application.Current.MainWindow.InvalidateVisual();` glad to know I wasn't super far off!

Answer (score 0):

I'm failing to see how your `Button` is actually being marked as disabled. I see the `CanExecute` bool being manipulated, but your button doesn't have `IsEnabled` bound. Even if that is the case, as @PaulSinnema said, you are only setting `CanExecute` to false (besides the first set in the constructor). I would suggest trying to set `CanExecute = true` **inside** of your `Task` and inside your lambda function (in the `BeginInvoke`) so then you can ensure the timing is correct. As you currently have it, your `AddPersonToCollection` method is doing the following:

1. Sets `CanExecute` to false
2. Fires off a task and waits for it to complete
3. Sets `CanExecute` to false

Here's my suggestion, hopefully it helps:

```
private async void AddPersonToCollection(object o)
    {
        CanExecute = false;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            /* Simulate a heavy workload*/
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                PeopleCollection.Add(new PersonModel
                {
                    Id = 0,
                    Name = "Foo bar"
                });
                // Setting it here ensures we flip it as soon as the collection has a person added
                CanExecute = true;
            });

            
            
        });
        // Remove this line
        ///CanExecute = false;
    }
```